# Axis2 JBoss Stax jar Issue

Tags: java, jboss, apache-axis, jboss-4.2.x

I am trying to use axis2 webservice client application, which seems to work fine on my machine but throws the exception below when I deploy it on a JBOSS 4.2.3 server. I believe its related to the stax implementation. I am currently using stax-api-1.0.1.jar. I have been stuck with this error for hours now, can someone pls help?

**Snapshot of included jars**

[image: I am using the following jars in my project]

**Exception**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory.newInstance(XMLInputFactory.java:136)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils$7.run(StAXUtils.java:504)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.newXMLInputFactory(StAXUtils.java:494)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory_perClassLoader(StAXUtils.java:574)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory(StAXUtils.java:171)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.getXMLInputFactory(StAXUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.util.StAXUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StAXUtils.java:223)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.factory.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createXMLStreamReader(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.factory.AbstractOMMetaFactory.createOMBuilder(AbstractOMMetaFactory.java:95)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:133)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(OMXMLBuilderFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:590)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.XMLUtils.toOM(XMLUtils.java:575)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DescriptionBuilder.buildOM(DescriptionBuilder.java:97)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.AxisConfigBuilder.populateConfig(AxisConfigBuilder.java:90)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:857)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(FileSystemConfigurator.java:116)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:210)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.configureServiceClient(ServiceClient.java:151)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.<init>(ServiceClient.java:144)
    at com.service_now.www.u_nsam_incident.ServiceNow_u_nsam_incidentStub.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.service_now.www.u_nsam_incident.ServiceNow_u_nsam_incidentStub.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.service_now.www.u_nsam_incident.ServiceNow_u_nsam_incidentStub.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.service_now.www.u_nsam_incident.ServiceNow_u_nsam_incidentStub.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.nomura.itsm.api.action.HDServiceAction.SNCreateHDTicket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at com.nomura.itsm.api.controller.ITSMService.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at com.nomura.itsm.api.controller.ITSMService.doGet(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.nomura.itsm.api.filter.EncodingFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:437)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:368)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ClassCastException is generally experienced in a managed environment because of conflicting resources on the classpath, or a difference between the version of the library compiled against and the version found in the runtime environment.

[Jarfinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory) is a nice site to find what libraries might also have the resource causing your problems.